# How to get scrolled position in textview? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

At the moment my app uses a scrollable text view to show text files- it's pretty simple, but what I'd like to do is have the app remember how far the view had been scrolled through for when it's reopened.

I know how to save the info, but I don't know how to find it in the first place- is there a way to get the position or coordinates of the current scrolling position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` extends `UIScrollView` which has `contentOffset`. That's a `CGPoint`. The `y` property is how far down the user has scrolled.